# Hide Div on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I coded a html form and would like to hide a div upon submission using javascript. For some reason the div isn't hiding.

**DIV & Form code:**

```
<div id="map"><iframe src="sourceurl" width="700" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><br />

<form method="get" action="<?php echo $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" onsubmit="mapHide(); return false;">

<select name="country" onchange='this.form.submit()'> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /><br>
</select>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function mapHide() {
document.getElementById('map').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: It probably is being hidden, but since your form posts back to itself you won't see it as the page is being re-loaded.

Comment: The form submits, the page reloads, and the javascript is lost.

Comment: you're returning `false` from the onsubmit, which disables the submit. did you awnt this form to actually submit to the server, or just hide the div and NOT actually submit anything?

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback guys, how should I solve this then, that when the form posts back to itself, it hides the form ?

Comment: @MarcB No the form is actually functioning and posts the data and returns it back, upon return of the data the div should hide itself

Comment: this'll never work, then. when the new page loads, the OLD page, on which you hit submit, and did the `.hide()`. is dead and gone. You'd have to set a cookie, or at least have the script which process the submission and returns data do the hiding there.

Comment: I amended my code to echo this with the content upon submission:`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#map").hide();
}` though the div is still not hiding

Comment: call the function again  -on onload

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be easier just using php.  Check if the the form has been submitted and display content accordingly.

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
//form was submitted content
}
else{
//empty form
}`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find a way to try and implement your above code

Comment: you put the form in the second brackets, and the form processing in the first brackets, including any messages to the client.

Answer (score 0):

you probably found a code meant for onsubmit and used it for an onchange event. I'm not an expert on this but based on what I've read so far, onchange="this.submit.form()" will refresh or reload your page therefore, everything just resets back.

I tried using your code and place it on a

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="this.form.submit();" />
```

and it works. 
So probably what you can do, is to do it using AJAX.